# How to select within a container with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom

```
<div id="container1">
<span>...</span>
</div>
<div id="container2">
<span>...</span>
</div>
```

Say if I have get the jQuery object $('container1'),how to find the `<span>` in it?

Comment: `$('container1')` will not select the element with that id but rather elements of that type, so nothing because there are no container1 elements. You forgot the #: `$('#container1')`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just select the [descendant](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/descendant#ancestordescendant) span:

```
$('#container1 span');
```

Note that this will select any span inside #container1, even if is not a direct descendant.

If you want to select only direct descendants, use the [parent > child](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/child#parentchild) selector:

```
$('#container1 > span');
```

If you have only an object reference you could:

```
$container1.find('span');
```

Or

```
$container1.children('span');
```

Answer (score 27):

I know you have accepted an answer, I'd just like to add another way of doing this:

```
$("span", $container1); //This will start in your variable $container1
                          and then look for all spans
```

I haven't tested performance on these yet, so I don't know which is better. Just thought I'd let you know you have more options (:

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of ways to do that. According to your comment at CMS answer:

```
$('#container1').find('span:first');
```

and

```
$('#container1 span:first');
```

on top of CMS's other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Use [find( expr )](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/find#expr). Example:

```
$("p").find("span").css('color','red');
```